# Multiple select for single row insert

Tags: postgresql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I need to insert a row into a table by selecting value from multiple tables. I want a row to be inserted from multiple tables.

```
insert into tab(id,name,date) values
((select max(id)+1 from tab),(select name from tab1),now());
```

Can you tell me how to do achieve this?

Whether this can be achieved by simple query itself or stored procedure is the only option?

Comment: How many rows does `tab1` have? If it has, say 100 rows, do you want 100 rows to be inserted into `tab`? It would also be good if you provided the `CREATE TABLE` scripts for both tables involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically achieved by writing a `SELECT` statement that outputs the fields in the same order as the `INSERT` statement and using that instead of a `VALUES` clause. For example, one might:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2)
SELECT t1.field1, max(t2.field2)
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (...)
GROUP BY t1.field1
WHERE something_else = 'whatever';
```

The point is that you can just do an

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...
```

to insert rows. You do not have to create a `VALUES` clause and mess with subqueries.